# why I am hitting TLE while passing large value of a and b?

Tags: c

I have following implementation for Extended Euclidean Algorithm: 
This is working  fine if I pass
`a < 9999` and `b < 9999`. But when I am passing large value for `a and b`. For example;
`a = 999999999` and `b = 999999999`, then I am facing TLE (Time limit exceeded) while execution.

I am not able to figure it out, **why** ?

```
long long int gcdExtended(long long int a, long long int b, long long int *x, long long int *y) 
{
    // Base Case
    if (a == 0) {
        *x = 0;
        *y = 1;
        return b;
    }

    long long int x1, y1; // To store results of recursive call
    long long int gcd = gcdExtended(b % a, a, &x1, &y1);

    // Update x and y using results of recursive call
    *x = y1 - (b / a) * x1;
    *y = x1;

    return gcd;
}
```

Code Link: http://ideone.com/fbMfao

Comment: What time limit? Also, typically recursive algorithms are slower than strict looping constructs, but it's unlikely to matter too much here; the whole point of the extended Euclidean algorithm is that it doesn't require that many steps.

Comment: If this is an "online challenge" problem you are solving, the obvious solution will probably hit TLE. It's your job to solve it with a more astute method.

Comment: Yeah, number of steps required in the Euclidean Algorithm is at most five 
times the number of digits in the smaller integer. So that should not be problem.

What time limit?
>> I have shared code link on ideone, and it hits TLE there :(

Comment: I don't think your problem is related to this function.  When I run the code from your ideone, it seems to be stuck in the `while ((x1 + (d * t) / h) < 0 || (y1 + (u * t) / h) < 0)` loop in `main`.  Another reason to always post a ***complete*** program that exhibits the problem; it's usually not where you think.

Comment: Oh, it's looping infinitely because `t` is 0.  Probably it overflowed

Comment: @nate  In my case t can't be zero. it will always be a positive number.

Comment: @AmitSharma: When an integer overflows, all bets are off.  Pop quiz: take any 64-bit number and add it to itself (i.e. double it) 64 times.  What do you get?